# [RESOLVED]Various programs not working after yum install some packages

Tags: rhel, package-management

[RESOLVED] I found out that the Memory chip caused the problems. I changed it and the system works fine now!

---

I'm using RHEL6.0 and encountered the problem that gdb, yum, rpm don't work any more. Perhaps package dependencies caused the problem.

```
# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-ia32:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0 (Santiago)
Release:    6.0
Codename:   Santiago

# uname -a
Linux electronics.server 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue Mar 25 17:17:46 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Running `gdb` either returns an error or crashes randomly:

```
#gdb
gdb: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0: undefined symbol: yCodec_Lookup
```

`yum` also fails:

```
#yum
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpm/_rpmmodule.so: undefined symbol: headerKsEntry

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:37:14) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I used `rpm` to check:

```
# rpm -V python yum
error: rpmdb: damaged header #759 retrieved -- skipping.
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#     764 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
package python is not installed
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#     764 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#     764 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#     764 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#     764 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1107 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
Unsatisfied dependencies for yum-3.2.29-43.el6.centos.noarch:
    /usr/bin/python is needed by yum-3.2.29-43.el6.centos.noarch
    python >= 2.4 is needed by yum-3.2.29-43.el6.centos.noarch
    python(abi) = 2.6 is needed by yum-3.2.29-43.el6.centos.noarch
    python-sqlite is needed by yum-3.2.29-43.el6.centos.noarch
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpmUtils/miscutils.pyc
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpmUtils/oldUtils.pyc
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpmUtils/oldUtils.pyo
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpmUtils/updates.pyc
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpmUtils/updates.pyo
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.pyc
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/misc.pyo
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/packageSack.pyc
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/packageSack.pyo
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/packages.py
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/packages.pyo
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/parser.py
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/plugins.pyc
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/plugins.pyo
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/repoMDObject.pyc
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/repoMDObject.pyo
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/rpmsack.py
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/rpmsack.pyc
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/rpmsack.pyo
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.pyc
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/update_md.pyc
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/update_md.pyo
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.pyc
..5......    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.pyo
..5......  d /usr/share/doc/yum-3.2.29/COPYING
..5......  d /usr/share/doc/yum-3.2.29/ChangeLog
..5......    /usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/yum.mo
..5......    /usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/yum.mo
..5......    /usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/yum.mo
..5......    /usr/share/locale/pa/LC_MESSAGES/yum.mo
..5......    /usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/yum.mo
..5......    /usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/yum.mo
..5......    /usr/share/locale/sr@latin/LC_MESSAGES/yum.mo
..5......    /usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/yum.mo
..5......    /usr/share/yum-cli/callback.py
..5......    /usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py
..5......    /usr/share/yum-cli/cli.pyo
..5......    /usr/share/yum-cli/output.py
..5......    /usr/share/yum-cli/utils.pyc
..5......    /usr/share/yum-cli/utils.pyo
..5......    /usr/share/yum-cli/yumcommands.pyc
..5......    /usr/share/yum-cli/yumcommands.pyo

# rpm -V rpm rpm-python
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1306 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
package rpm is not installed
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1307 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
package rpm-python is not installed
*** glibc detected *** rpm: free(): invalid pointer: 0x09118fea ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0x3bfe31]
/lib/libnspr4.so(PR_Free+0x28)[0x2feee98]
/lib/libplds4.so[0x318a6b]
/lib/libplds4.so(PL_HashTableDestroy+0x67)[0x3181e7]
/usr/lib/libnssutil3.so(SECOID_Shutdown+0x26)[0x2fc7046]
/usr/lib/libnss3.so[0x302f3b1]
/usr/lib/libnss3.so(NSS_Shutdown+0x85)[0x302f5f5]
/usr/lib/librpmio.so.1(rpmFreeCrypto+0x24)[0x76d4d4]
/usr/lib/librpm.so.1(rpmFreeRpmrc+0x3b9)[0x160379]
rpm[0x8049e31]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0x365d26]
rpm[0x8049531]
======= Memory map: ========
0011d000-00181000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 533150     /usr/lib/librpm.so.1.0.0
00181000-00185000 rw-p 00064000 fd:00 533150     /usr/lib/librpm.so.1.0.0
00185000-00186000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00186000-00192000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2491287    /lib/libnss_files-2.12.so
00192000-00193000 r--p 0000b000 fd:00 2491287    /lib/libnss_files-2.12.so
00193000-00194000 rw-p 0000c000 fd:00 2491287    /lib/libnss_files-2.12.so
00194000-001d5000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 532562     /usr/lib/libsoftokn3.so
001d5000-001d6000 r--p 00040000 fd:00 532562     /usr/lib/libsoftokn3.so
001d6000-001d7000 rw-p 00041000 fd:00 532562     /usr/lib/libsoftokn3.so
00317000-0031a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2491739    /lib/libplds4.so
0031a000-0031b000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 2491739    /lib/libplds4.so
0031b000-0031c000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 2491739    /lib/libplds4.so
0031e000-00322000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2491738    /lib/libplc4.so
00322000-00323000 r--p 00003000 fd:00 2491738    /lib/libplc4.so
00323000-00324000 rw-p 00004000 fd:00 2491738    /lib/libplc4.so
00329000-00347000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2491272    /lib/ld-2.12.so
00347000-00348000 r--p 0001d000 fd:00 2491272    /lib/ld-2.12.so
00348000-00349000 rw-p 0001e000 fd:00 2491272    /lib/ld-2.12.so
0034f000-004e0000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2491286    /lib/libc-2.12.so
004e0000-004e2000 r--p 00191000 fd:00 2491286    /lib/libc-2.12.so
004e2000-004e3000 rw-p 00193000 fd:00 2491286    /lib/libc-2.12.so
004e3000-004e6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
004e8000-004eb000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2491500    /lib/libdl-2.12.so
004eb000-004ec000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 2491500    /lib/libdl-2.12.so
004ec000-004ed000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 2491500    /lib/libdl-2.12.so
004ef000-00506000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2491341    /lib/libpthread-2.12.so
00506000-00507000 r--p 00016000 fd:00 2491341    /lib/libpthread-2.12.so
00507000-00508000 rw-p 00017000 fd:00 2491341    /lib/libpthread-2.12.so
00508000-0050a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0050c000-00513000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2491352    /lib/librt-2.12.so
00513000-00514000 r--p 00006000 fd:00 2491352    /lib/librt-2.12.so
00514000-00515000 rw-p 00007000 fd:00 2491352    /lib/librt-2.12.so
00517000-00529000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2491502    /lib/libz.so.1.2.3
00529000-0052a000 r--p 00011000 fd:00 2491502    /lib/libz.so.1.2.3
0052a000-0052b000 rw-p 00012000 fd:00 2491502    /lib/libz.so.1.2.3
0052d000-00555000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2491288    /lib/libm-2.12.so
00555000-00556000 r--p 00027000 fd:00 2491288    /lib/libm-2.12.so
00556000-00557000 rw-p 00028000 fd:00 2491288    /lib/libm-2.12.so
00559000-00574000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 542113     /usr/lib/libmagic.so.1.0.0
00574000-00575000 rw-p 0001b000 fd:00 542113     /usr/lib/libmagic.so.1.0.0
00575000-00577000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00579000-0059c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 530543     /usr/lib/librpmbuild.so.1.0.0
0059c000-0059e000 rw-p 00023000 fd:00 530543     /usr/lib/librpmbuild.so.1.0.0
0059e000-005a2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00667000-00684000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2491515    /lib/libselinux.so.1
00684000-00685000 r--p 0001c000 fd:00 2491515    /lib/libselinux.so.1
00685000-00686000 rw-p 0001d000 fd:00 2491515    /lib/libselinux.so.1
00688000-0069d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2491513    /lib/libresolv-2.12.so
0069d000-0069e000 ---p 00015000 fd:00 2491513    /lib/libresolv-2.12.so
0069e000-0069f000 r--p 00015000 fd:00 2491513    /lib/libresolv-2.12.so
0069f000-006a0000 rw-p 00016000 fd:00 2491513    /lib/libresolv-2.12.so
006a0000-006a2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
006a4000-006ba000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 539294     /usr/lib/libelf-0.152.so
006ba000-006bb000 r--p 00015000 fd:00 539294     /usr/lib/libelf-0.152.so
006bb000-006bc000 rw-p 00016000 fd:00 539294     /usr/lib/libelf-0.152.so
006be000-006ea000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 542941     /usr/lib/liblua-5.1.so
006ea000-006eb000 rw-p 0002c000 fd:00 542941     /usr/lib/liblua-5.1.so
00729000-0072a000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
00758000-00780000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 539241     /usr/lib/librpmio.so.1.0.0
00780000-00782000 rw-p 00028000 fd:00 539241     /usr/lib/librpmio.so.1.0.0
00782000-00784000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
007b5000-007b8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2494002    /lib/libcap.so.2.16
007b8000-007b9000 rw-p 00002000 fd:00 2494002    /lib/libcap.so.2.16
00909000-0090e000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2491285    /lib/libnss_dns-2.12.so
0090e000-0090f000 r--p 00004000 fd:00 2491285    /lib/libnss_dns-2.12.so
0090f000-00910000 rw-p 00005000 fd:00 2491285    /lib/libnss_dns-2.12.so
009b6000-00a10000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2491524    /lib/libfreebl3.so
00a10000-00a11000 r--p 00059000 fd:00 2491524    /lib/libfreebl3.so
00a11000-00a12000 rw-p 0005a000 fd:00 2491524    /lib/libfreebl3.so
00a12000-00a16000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00dea000-00df1000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2493999    /lib/libacl.so.1.1.0
00df1000-00df2000 r--p 00006000 fd:00 2493999    /lib/libacl.so.1.1.0
00df2000-00df3000 rw-p 00007000 fd:00 2493999    /lib/libacl.so.1.1.0
02bdb000-02bfe000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 535421     /usr/lib/liblzma.so.0.0.0
02bfe000-02bff000 rw-p 00022000 fd:00 535421     /usr/lib/liblzma.so.0.0.0
02dfc000-02e19000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2491333    /lib/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
02e19000-02e1a000 rw-p 0001d000 fd:00 2491333    /lib/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
02e70000-02efe000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 531021     /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
02efe000-02f00000 rw-p 0008d000 fd:00 531021     /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
02fb6000-02fd7000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 530325     /usr/lib/libnssutil3.so
02fd7000-02fda000 r--p 00021000 fd:00 530325     /usr/lib/libnssutil3.so
02fda000-02fdb000 rw-p 00024000 fd:00 530325     /usr/lib/libnssutil3.so
02fdd000-03017000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2491734    /lib/libnspr4.so
03017000-03018000 r--p 00039000 fd:00 2491734    /lib/libnspr4.so
03018000-03019000 rw-p 0003a000 fd:00 2491734    /lib/libnspr4.so
03019000-0301b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0301d000-03154000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 530395     /usr/lib/libnss3.so
03154000-03157000 r--p 00136000 fd:00 530395     /usr/lib/libnss3.so
03157000-03159000 rw-p 00139000 fd:00 530395     /usr/lib/libnss3.soAborted (core dumped)
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

```
# mv /var/lib/rpm /var/lib/rpm.bak
# mkdir /var/lib/rpm
# cp /var/lib/rpm.bak/Packages /var/lib/rpm/
# rpm --rebuilddb
rpmdb: page 0: illegal page type or format
rpmdb: PANIC: Invalid argument
error: db3 error(-30974) from dbcursor->c_get: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
error: error(-30974) getting "/usr/lib/" records from Dirnames index
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from dbcursor->c_get: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
error: error(-30974) getting "/usr/share/doc/" records from Dirnames index
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from dbcursor->c_get: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
error: error(-30974) getting "/usr/share/doc/libXau-1.0.6/" records from Dirnames index
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from dbcursor->c_close: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from db->sync: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from db_create: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
error: cannot open Requireversion index using db3 -  (-30974)
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from db_create: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
error: cannot open Provideversion index using db3 -  (-30974)
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from db_create: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
error: cannot open Installtid index using db3 -  (-30974)
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from db_create: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
error: cannot open Sigmd5 index using db3 -  (-30974)
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from db_create: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
error: cannot open Sha1header index using db3 -  (-30974)
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from db_create: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
error: cannot open Filedigests index using db3 -  (-30974)
error: cannot add record originally at 769
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from db->close: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from db->close: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from db->close: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from db->close: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from db->close: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from db->close: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from db->close: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
rpmdb: File handles still open at environment close
rpmdb: Open file handle: /var/lib/rpmrebuilddb.16120/Packages
rpmdb: Open file handle: /var/lib/rpmrebuilddb.16120/Name
rpmdb: Open file handle: /var/lib/rpmrebuilddb.16120/Basenames
rpmdb: Open file handle: /var/lib/rpmrebuilddb.16120/Group
rpmdb: Open file handle: /var/lib/rpmrebuilddb.16120/Requirename
rpmdb: Open file handle: /var/lib/rpmrebuilddb.16120/Providename
rpmdb: Open file handle: /var/lib/rpmrebuilddb.16120/Dirnames
rpmdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
error: db3 error(-30974) from dbenv->close: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
warning: failed to rebuild database: original database remains in place
error: failed to remove directory /var/lib/rpmrebuilddb.16120: No such file or directory
```

reinstall `rpm-python` and `python` fails:

```
# rpm -ivh --force rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.i686.rpm python-2.6.6-51.el6.i686.rpm 
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1156 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1156 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1156 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1156 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1156 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1186 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1156 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1156 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1156 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#     765 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1156 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#     838 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1306 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1156 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1156 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#    1156 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#     765 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#     766 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6 is needed by rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) is needed by rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.i686
    libelf.so.1 is needed by rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.i686
    libm.so.6 is needed by rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.i686
    libpthread.so.0 is needed by rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.i686
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.i686
    libpython2.6.so.1.0 is needed by rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.i686
    librt.so.1 is needed by rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.i686
    libselinux.so.1 is needed by rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.i686
    rpm = 4.8.0-37.el6 is needed by rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.i686
    rtld(GNU_HASH) is needed by rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.i686
    libc.so.6 is needed by python-2.6.6-51.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by python-2.6.6-51.el6.i686
    libdl.so.2 is needed by python-2.6.6-51.el6.i686
    libm.so.6 is needed by python-2.6.6-51.el6.i686
    libpthread.so.0 is needed by python-2.6.6-51.el6.i686
    libpython2.6.so.1.0 is needed by python-2.6.6-51.el6.i686
    libutil.so.1 is needed by python-2.6.6-51.el6.i686
    python-libs(x86-32) = 2.6.6-51.el6 is needed by python-2.6.6-51.el6.i686
    rtld(GNU_HASH) is needed by python-2.6.6-51.el6.i686
```

Comment: What did you do just before this? It looks like you've removed the `python` package.

Comment: The `python` package still here. Perhaps I run `yum update` before.  I try `yum undo` but the yum aready broken.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your rpmdb is corrupted, `rpm -V python` says `package python is not installed`, but `yum` even tells you what python version you have.
So First of all try to rebuild your rpmdb:

```
mv /var/lib/rpm /var/lib/rpm.bak
mkdir /var/lib/rpm
cp /var/lib/rpm.bak/packages /var/lib/rpm
rpm --rebuilddb
restorecon -r /var/lib/rpm
```

afterwards re-run `rpm -V python yum` and run `yum check`.

---

If your rpmdb could not be rebuild, remove `/var/lib/rpm`, move the `/var/lib/rpm.bak` back and run `restorecon -vr /var/lib/rpm` if you get some output, run `rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__*` followed by a re-run of `rpm --rebuilddb`

---

If this could not fix it too, manually download `rpm-python` and `python` from redhat repository and install via `rpm -i rpm-python python` afterwards try again the `rpm --rebuilddb`

Comment: I have try, but rpm rebuild error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have try all the commands but still not work. the `rpm` also broken.